# Why legacy-install -failure error occur during pip install pillow command ?How to remove this pillow error?

Tags: python

```
 [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: You will have to check and share the other parts of the logs for more information. That just looks like the generic logs when pip install fails for any package. Also, share more details of your system (OS, Python version, etc.). Please [edit] your question to add these details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.